# Transposing a large csv file

Tags: csv, transpose

I have a huge csv file in this format

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksQzS.png

I want to tanspose it in this format 
I tried a lot but unable to achieve it. Is there some way i can do using awk.
The file contains thousands of records

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHQ52.png

Comment: Define "huge". What OS are you using? What are your field separators?

Comment: There is nearly 25000 records in the file . OS : Unix and file separator is  |

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Show details. What worked and what doesn't? This is not the place to ask others to write your code.

Comment: i have tried using SQL  which was working fine in Oracle, but when i tried using the same approach in hive, I was unable to do it. Since I don't have any access to Oracle in my current work environment, I need some way to do using awk. Since I am not a pro in awk, I am seeking help from the gurus here. @meangreen, I know it is not the place to make others write my code, but I know, this is the only place where I can get some pointers to do the task,

Answer (score 2):

My `awk` skills are more "functional" than "elegant" but this might get you started

```
awk -F'|' '{for(f=1;f<=NF;f++){x[NR subsep f]=$f}} END{for(f=1;f<=NF;f++){p="";for(r=1;r<=NR;r++){if(length(p))p=p "|";p=p x[r subsep f]}print p}}' file.csv
r1f1|r2f1|r3f1
r1f2|r2f2|r3f2
r1f3|r2f3|r3f3
r1f4|r2f4|r3f4
r1f5|r2f5|r3f5
```

**file.csv**

```
r1f1|r1f2|r1f3|r1f4|r1f5
r2f1|r2f2|r2f3|r2f4|r2f5
r3f1|r3f2|r3f3|r3f4|r3f5
```

So, for every line of your inout file, the fields are saved into a 2-D array, called `x[]`, indexed by line number (NR) and field number (1..NF). At the end of your input file, inside the `END{}`, I iterate through the number of fields and number of records in the file and print out the transpose, adding in pipe symbols, if necessary, as I go.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not know how to do this in awk.  However, if you don't mind using Python, this kind of data reshaping is simple.  For example:

```
import scipy, pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    "s1_x": scipy.randn(10),
    "s1_y": scipy.randn(10),
    "s2_x": scipy.randn(10),
    "s2_y": scipy.randn(10)
    })
```

`df` is initially shaped as follows:

```
       s1_x      s1_y      s2_x      s2_y
0 -0.075796  2.191362 -0.960267  0.619519
1 -1.201713  0.015710  0.121307 -0.273759
2 -0.549812  1.089105 -0.525985  1.383265
```

But if you use `df.stack()` it becomes:

```
0  s1_x   -0.075796
   s1_y    2.191362
   s2_x   -0.960267
   s2_y    0.619519
1  s1_x   -1.201713
   s1_y    0.015710
   s2_x    0.121307
   s2_y   -0.273759
2  s1_x   -0.549812
   s1_y    1.089105
   s2_x   -0.525985
   s2_y    1.383265
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Forgot to add: check out the pandas documentation (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html) for much more detail on how this works.